# You to know how many sectors to load from in the boot loader

Tags: kernel, boot, boot-loader

So I was exploring how boot loaders works and I came across one question that I can't seem to find any answer. *How does the boot loader knows exactly how many sectors it has to read to load the whole kernel ?*

I'm writing a boot loader and it's a pain in the ass to have to manually change how many sectors to read by calculating the exact amount of sectors. Surely there is a way to automate this process but I don't know how. I heard about filesystems, BPB and BDB and I get confused about all of those things. I truly want to know how the whole process works. Fat12 is a simple filesystem but what happens if the kernel is **too big** for a floppy disk ?

Any explanation would be welcome.

Comment: Ask one question at a time! The boot loader needs to understand the filesystem in order to find the blocks. Once you know it understands the file system it just reads all of the file to get the file! If the kernel is too big for a floppy disk you need to invent a new boot loader that will load part of the kernel from a floppy, prompt the user to change floppies, read the rest of the kernel from a second floppy and then start it. I am not aware that anyone has done that.

Comment: Are you talking about the primary bootloader or secondary bootloader?

Comment: Years ago, if the kernel was too big for the floppy, you stripped out drivers (and made them into modules) until it wasn't.  The main reason for compiling a kernel then was to customize it so it had only the bare minimum of drivers needed for your system.  Today, floppy drives are out of production and everyone boots from hard drives, so we load the kernel along with an initrd that contains nearly every driver in existence.

Comment: Which OS are you asking about?

Comment: @icarus Well, I didn't think about that at all. My goal was to know how exactly it nows how many sectors to read. By that I mean for example, we don't have any filesystem, it's just a boot loader with the kernel placed right after the boot loader. How theoretically the bootloader would know how many sectors it has to read to load the kernel ?

Comment: @JimL. A basic kernel I wrote, not any specific OS

Comment: @StephenHarris It can be the primary or the secondary. Let's say it's a two stage boot loader. The first stage loads 512 bytes, in other words the second stage. And the second stage loads the whole kernel. But let's say I haven't implemented any filesystem, the whole thing is just the Bootloader and the kernel placed right after this one.

Comment: "Two" stage boot loaders are actually the second and third stages of booting. For an x86 PC, prior to UEFI, it just loaded the first sector of the boot device (The MBR, master boot record) into memory and executed it. The code in the MBR can do anything you can fit into the size. For example it could read the second sector, read say the byte at location 4 and use that to say how many more sectors to read, or it could loop reading sectors until it found one filled with 0xff bytes.

Comment: @icarus I thought about one similar solution. Loop till reading fails. But I wasn't sure if that could be possible using the interrupt 0x13.

Comment: Reading until it fails seems a very good way to have slow boot performance. Set up even a modest 2TB disk drive as a boot device. It will have a sustained read speed of less than 100 megabytes a second, so will take over 20,000 seconds to read, say 6 hours.

Comment: @icarus Of course that's the downside of this strategy. Maybe having a way for the kernel to store its size at the very first byte of it would be a better idea ? I'm having a hard time to imagine how we could implement that

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and ask what you are trying to do. Assuming a "legacy" boot sequence, on a "PC", you get to write about 440 bytes of assembly code to keep compatibility with a standard MBR partitioning scheme. Typically this will load some more code from the first "track", and you start the first partition after that. As the concept of "track" is almost obsolete, people put the first partition to start at sector 64. So have MBR load always 63 sectors worth of data. Put the kernel in the filesystem, and have the bootloader know how to read files from the filesystem.

Comment: You probably need to research writing linker scripts if you are not writing your system in assembler. These are a staple of embedded programming. These allow you to put the lengths or other data into output files at fixed locations.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional boot loaders were multistage.  The first stage bootloader for a system with an MBR partition table had the bootloader in the same block as the partition table, right after the partition table.

This code would look at the partition table, find a primary partition with the bootable flag set ("made active"), and then run the code in the first block of that partition.   That code (generally not much more complicated than the first code) would then load the second stage bootloader.  Several techniques were used to find the second stage boot loader, including just reading all the blocks remaining in the track, and using a blocklist written into that track to load specific blocks  (LILO took this later approach).

The second stage bootloader generally was smart enough to know how to find the rest of the operating system in the filesystem of the partition it was booting from.

More modern systems use UEFI, where the firmware itself has a miniature operating system that is at least smart enough to read FAT format partitions and can load and verify standard format EFI executables from the FAT format EFI partition, and these typically are now your second stage loader which fully understand the operating system's specific partition format to load the rest of the operating system.

If you are writing your own operating system, the easiest way to handle this would probably to start by writing EFI format executables.

Comment: yep, LILO stores (stored) a list of blocks to read at install time, [it couldn't read the filesystem from the bootloader itself](https://www.joonet.de/lilo/olddoc/html/user_21-53.html#fn3x0). Grub can read filesystems though, so it just needs a file name.